# Point to an object's property in a timeout

Tags: javascript

I have a simple object like this:

```
myObject.percentage =  2;
bar = document.getElementByID('the_div');
```

So i then have this:

```
function upgrade_bar(bar,percentage) {
console.log(percentage);

    bar._timer = setTimeout(function () {
            upgrade_bar(bar,percentage)
        }, 10000);
} 
upgrade_bar(bar,myObject.percentage);

myObject.percentage = 4;
//upgrade_bar still console.logs 2 instead of 4
```

So whilst this is running, else where `percentage` is changing.

But inside the `upgrade_bar` function it is still `2` which is what it started as.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use a pointer so it will not pass the value but pass a reference so its always up to date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have pass-by-reference arguments.

What you can do is pass the object itself and reference its property. And, regarding your comments about different properties, you can add another argument to know which to use.

```
function upgrade_bar(bar, settings, key) {
    key = key || 'percentage';
    console.log(settings[key]);

    bar._timer = setTimeout(function () {
        upgrade_bar(bar, settings, key);
    }, 10000);
}

upgrade_bar(bar, myObject, 'percentage');
```

Comment: This limits me to using only one object its not very flexible should i make progress bars for other aspects. It would mean i need a function for every object =/

Comment: @Dave It allows you to pass in any `Object` that has a `percentage` property. How is that not flexible?

Comment: Yeh but in my situation they are together example `myObject.percentage` `myObject.percentage2` what if i parse a string and do `myObject[string]` =/

Comment: @Dave It can be take a 3rd argument for the property name (`key`). See my edit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i need to tell it either use percentage2 or percentage1.

Comment: @Dave: Fortunately, Jonathan understood that. His edit does it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski ah thats perfect :)

Comment: Why does it limit you? You can just pass a new reference to upgrade that bar?

Comment: @Steven10172 it doesn't now i can send different keys, that was where i was stuck :)